# How to build shiboken on Window XP + MinGW + Qt4.8.1

Tags: python, qt, cmake, pyside

I was trying to build shiboken 1.1.2 from source with configuration of Window XP + MinGW+Qt4.8.1 but always got below error.
Believe it’s  because I didn’t install libxml2 and libxslt. So I installed these 2 application using their windows binary installer. After they were installed, I added their bin folders to my PATH and camke shiboken again. Same error. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Zhu

```
D:\shiboken-1.1.2\build>cmake .. -G"MinGW Makefiles"
-- Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing:  LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "2.6.32")
-- Could NOT find LibXslt (missing:  LIBXSLT_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.1.19")
CMake Warning at ApiExtractor/CMakeLists.txt:12 (message):
  libxslt and/or libxml not found, disabling support for doc strings!


-- sphinx-build - not found! doc target disabled
-- Tests will be generated avoiding the protected hack!
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/shiboken-1.1.2/build
```

Comment: Have you added `LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR` and `LIBXSLT_INCLUDE_DIR` to your `PATH`?

Comment: thanks! LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR is the folder of header files for libxml2 or the folder of the installation root of libxml2?

Comment: I've never heard of either library, but presumably they are both for the header files directory.  A quick internet search will confirm.